# Finding difference is not working

Tags: python, difference, array-difference

I am trying to find difference from two files but still I get answer from two files

This is my code

```
#File one(This file contents should be removed after comparing file two)
a = open('diff1','r+')
#File two
#This file has 999999 records
b = open('gtin','r+')
f8 = open('missing-test-remove.txt','w')
def diff(a, b):
    c = set(a).union(set(b))
    d = set(a).intersection(set(b))
    result =  list(c - d)
    for s in result:
        print s
        f8.write(s)

diff(a,b)
```

But still I get same results from two files but file one contents should  be removed after comparing with file two

Comment: please use context managers when working with files.  `with open('diff1') as a:`...

Comment: You just want to have a new list  to write after you compared the two files and removed the elements that were duplicate from `File one`?

Comment: You might find it simpler to use `filecmp` from the standard library https://docs.python.org/2/library/filecmp.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing wrong is -

```
c = set(a).union(set(b))
d = set(a).intersection(set(b))
```

Please note `a` and `b` are still file descriptors, once you do `set(a)` , if you do `set(a)` again, you will get an empty set, because in the first call to `set(a)`  , the complete file has already been read and the cursor for the file is at the end.

You need to change your code such that you only call `set(a)` and `set(b) once. Something along the lines of -

```
#File one(This file contents should be removed after comparing file two)
a = open('diff1','r+')
#File two
#This file has 999999 records
b = open('gtin','r+')
f8 = open('missing-test-remove.txt','w')
def diff(a, b):
    sa = set(a)
    sb = set(b)
    c = sa.union(sb)
    d = sa.intersection(sb)
    result =  list(c - d)
    for s in result:
        print s
        f8.write(s)

diff(a,b)
```

Also, you should flush the file to which you write , after completing the write and at the end close all files as -

```
a.close()
b.close()
f8.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the set value. A simple test:

```
    print a
    print set(a)
    print a
    print set(a) # wrong
```

So

```
    seta = set(a)
    setb = set(b)
    setc = seta.union(setb)
    setd = seta.intersection(setb)
```